# Python asyncio stuck for some reason

Tags: python, web-crawler, python-asyncio

I was trying to run one of the examples from this 
[page](https://compiletoi.net/fast-scraping-in-python-with-asyncio/). For some reason it doesn't work, if you run this program it will print random amount of "hi" and after that it will stuck. I am using python 3.6.0, can you please help me to figure out what is the problem?

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import bs4


@asyncio.coroutine
def print_page(url):
    response = yield from aiohttp.request('GET', url)
    body = yield from response.text()
    print(body)


@asyncio.coroutine
def get(*args, **kwargs):
    response = yield from aiohttp.request('GET', *args, **kwargs)
    return (yield from response.text())


def first_magnet(page):
    return "hi"


@asyncio.coroutine
def print_magnet(query):
    url = 'http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/J/J{}/'.format(query)
    page = yield from get(url, compress=True)
    magnet = first_magnet(page)
    print('{}: {}'.format(query, magnet))


distros = range(80,90)
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
f = asyncio.wait([print_magnet(d) for d in distros])
loop.run_until_complete(f)
```

Comment: `return (yield from response.text())` sounds weird to me...

Comment: Your code works fine for me, the program returns properly after printing `8X: hi` ten times. Also, consider using the [async/await](http://asyncio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/hello_world.html#simple-coroutine) syntax if you're using python>=3.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm code stucks on Python 3.6.1 for Windows.

Looks like problem somehow related to `compress=True` param. If you remove it code will be finished fine.

I think you should report this bug to aiohttp [issue tracker](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues).